# Combine two paths with common folder

Tags: python

Is there a way in python to combine two paths with `os.path` or any other library which doesn't repeat common subfolders? i.e.

```
root = '/home/user/test'

rel_path = 'test/files/file.txt'

os.combine(root, rel_path)
```

And returning `/home/user/test/files/file.txt` instead `/home/user/test/test/files/file.txt`

Comment: I doubt there is because there might as well be a `test` folder inside the `test` folder..

Comment: Yeah, was wondering if there is any build in or lib I could use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to do it manually, I don't think os.path implements this functionality.

Maybe try something like:

```
def combine_with_duplicate(root, rel_path):
    rs = root.split("/")
    rps = rel_path.split("/")
    popped = False
    for v in rs:
        if v == rps[0]:
            rps.pop(0)
            popped = True
        elif popped:
            break

    return "/".join(rs+rps)


print(combine_with_duplicate('/home/user/test', 'test/files/file.txt'))
# /home/user/test/files/file.txt
print(combine_with_duplicate('/home/user', 'test/files/file.txt'))
# /home/user/test/files/file.txt
print(combine_with_duplicate('/home/user/test', 'user/test/files/file.txt'))
# /home/user/test/files/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.path.join`:

```
import os

root = '/home/user/test'

rel_path = 'test/files/file.txt'

head, tail = os.path.split(root)
final = os.path.join(head, rel_path)

print(final)
#  /home/user/test/files/file.txt
```

Comment: what if `root = '/home/user/test/files'` ? You have to go recursive

Comment: This will unfortunately only work if the last part of the root matches the first part of the rel path. To do it recursively you have to write custom code. And recursive will come with its own set of problems.

Comment: I know, that's why I am "asking". And OP did not limit the size of the overlap to one common folder.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis , taking your feedback , review my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
>>> import os
>>> root = '/home/user/test'
>>> rel_path = 'test/files/file.txt'
>>> os.path.join(root, '../', rel_path)
'/home/user/test/../test/files/file.txt'
```

Or this, in case of root and rel_path have not 'overlapping' parts:

```
>>> os.path.join(root, '../' if root.split('/')[-1] == rel_path.split('/')[0] else '' , rel_path)
'/home/user/test/../test/files/file.txt'
>>> root =  '/home/user/test/files'
>>> os.path.join(root, '../' if root.split('/')[-1] == rel_path.split('/')[0] else '' , rel_path)
'/home/user/test/files/test/files/file.txt'
```

Comment: what if `root = '/home/user/test/files'` ? You have to go recursive